# get error when passing result into database

Tags: android

how to pass the result into database? i get the error which is "Cannot invoke getText() on the primitive type int". Below is my code:

```
private void saveTotalAttack() {
    DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

    if (getIntent().getExtras() == null) {

        dbConnector.InsertTotalAttack(
                sumAttackS.getText().toString());
    } 
}
```

PS: sumAttack is the result of X + Y. Any idea for passing this result into database? On the top, i declare sumAttack as int. Please help!

Comment: Can you tell me the type of sumAttackS?

Comment: i declare sumAttackS as String

Comment: I am wondering why you need to call method getText() on string type variable as far you can pass it as a parameter to calling method

Comment: what should i call then?

Comment: Post the logcat, more detail and what you have tried? so that other can answer your question

Comment: my question is, result = X + Y and how to insert result into database?

Answer (score 0):

To insert the value in database

```
public void inserdata(String result)
    {
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put("your_column_name", result);
        db.insert("your_table_name", null, cv);
    }
```

Comment: if(attack_edit.getText() != null || attackF_edit.getText() != null){
    attack = attack_edit.getText().toString();
    attackF = attackF_edit.getText().toString();
    
    return sumAttack = (attack + attackF) * attack / 10; 
  }

Comment: The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String

Comment: what happen? any problem?